# Issue while reading binary file

Tags: c

I am trying to read binary file using `fread()` but I keep getting a segmentation fault. I am sure the following code is correct:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("User/Admin/dataset.bin", "rb");
double *data = calloc(30 * 4, sizeof(double));
fread(data, sizeof(double), 30 * 4, fp);
```

Does anyone see an issue here! I really don't see it!!

Comment: you did not check to see if the open worked

Comment: There's probably a bug elsewhere in your code.  Run your program though [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  If you're reading/writing someplace you shouldn't, it will tell you.

Comment: I'm guessing it's your file path, which is currently relative to where you execute this, since there's no forward-slash in front.

Comment: Despite your certainty, the fact that your program exhibits a segmentation fault proves that *something* is wrong with it.  But perhaps the problem is somewhere else in it.  Your chances of getting a useful answer will be much improved if you present a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the returns of `fopen` and `calloc`? You might be running into an issue with the file you are trying to read not being accessible (either not found or insufficient permissions) or your `calloc` could be failing to allocate memory.

You need to check the returned pointers to see if they are `NULL` like so:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("User/Admin/dataset.bin", "rb");
if(fp == NULL){
    perror("Failed to open file:\n");
    return; // or however you want to handle this
}
double *data = calloc(30 * 4, sizeof(double));
if(data == NULL){
     perror("Failed to allocate space for data pointer:\n");
     fclose(fp);
     return; // or however you want to handle this
}
fread(data, sizeof(double), 30 * 4, fp);
```

More than likely, the issue here is either insufficient privileges to open `User/Admin/dataset.bin` or the file path is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

if code is right, and file can be opened successfully, may be the file size is smaller than `30*4*sizeof(double)`

Comment: Wouldn't matter, you would just receive a *short item count*, e.g. `man 3 fread` "*If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).*'.